# Compiling with Oracle javac vs OpenJDK javac

Tags: java

Our software previously shipped with the OpenJDK JRE, but now we are going to ship the Oracle JRE.

Previously we compiled with the OpenJDK javac compiler. I assume now we should use the Oracle javac compiler as it is more likely to generate problem free code when run with the Oracle JRE. Is this correct?

If so how can the javac vendor be verified? I would want the makefile to error out if using the wrong compiler (our old software version would use the OpenJDK compiler, while the new version would use Oracle compiler).

Comment: Any Java compiler should work with any Java runtime.

Answer (score 5):

> but now we are going to ship the Oracle JRE.

I suspect you can't do this legally.

> I assume now we should use the Oracle javac compiler as it is more likely to generate problem free code when run with the Oracle JRE. Is this correct?

The `javac` uses the same source code as OpenJDK and it should produce the same or compatible byte code even if it doesn't.